# How to start an activity that is in a jar file?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-simple-facebook

I'm working on an android app which uses `facebook sdk` and the `android-simple-facebook` library (a "wrapper" library).
The `android-simple-facebook` lib depends on `facebook sdk` and my app depends on `android-simple-facebook`.

I created a jar file (via Artificats in IDEA's Module Settings) containing the compile output of both libraries.
I need the `facebook sdk` compile output too because I have this reference to facebook's LoginActivity in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

The reason I created this jar file is that i'm not the only developer working on this project, and I don't want anyone who develops this project to reference 2 libraries. I just want them to work with a static jar I create.
So the jar get's created and everything is fine, no compile errors, but when calling the login() function, which starts facebook's LoginActivity I guess, I get the following exception:

```
Unable to resume activity {com.example.example/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02000a
```

**What I suspect is**, `LoginActivity.onCreate()` executes `setContentView(R.layout.com_facebook_login_activity_layout)` but I don't see any resources (the layout files for example) inside the jar file.

Any help on how to accomplish my goal of having one working jar will be greatly appreciated!

---

Some additional info about my setup:

- My `libs` folder and jar's contents:
  [image: libs and jar contens]
- Artificat settings:
  [image: Artificat settings]

Comment: Your fundamental problem leading to that error may be that an Android jar can include only code, and not resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is adding the libraries (repositories) as sub-modules in git and as modules in my project.
So, I don't know if the answer is really "No, it can't be done", but that's how I solved the problem for now.

Hope it helps anyone.